# how to add constructor in kotlin using Spring boot?

Tags: java, kotlin

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class InfoServerSpringApplication {

//this is my code in java
public InfoServerSpringApplication() {
    System.out.println("Hello world");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(InfoServerSpringApplication.class, args);
}
}
```

so that's how i print hello world in Spring boot java , i use constructor but how about in kotlin ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
class Kotlin2Application

//constructor code to print hello world in kotlin

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Kotlin2Application>(*args)
}
```

I'm using eclipse. Is there any solution please ?

Answer (score 2):

You can run code when an instance is created by using an *initializer block* (or even multiple ones), code placed in these becomes part of the body of the primary constructor.

```
class Kotlin2Application {
    init {
        println("Hello world")
    }
}
```

(This is just a general answer about how to translate the specific Java code in question, not to be taken as best practice for running code after your Spring application starts.)

See also: [official documentation about classes and constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors).

Answer (score 0):

1. Please try with this.

   ```
   class Kotlin2Application {
         constructor(){
           println("Hello world")
        }
   }
   ```